# Why numpy array is not of Sequence type?

Tags: python, numpy, python-typing

Help understand why numpy array is not a Sequence type object.

```
from typing import Sequence
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3])
isinstance(x, Sequence)
---
False
```

- [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence)

> An iterable which supports efficient element access using integer indices via the `__getitem__()` special method and defines a `__len__()` method that returns the length of the sequence. Some built-in sequence types are list, str, tuple, and bytes. Note that dict also supports `__getitem__()` and `__len__()`, but is considered a mapping rather than a sequence because the lookups use arbitrary immutable keys rather than integers.
>
> The [collections.abc.Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) abstract base class defines a much richer interface that goes beyond just `__getitem__()` and `__len__()`, adding count(), index(), `__contains__()`, and `__reversed__()`.

Comment: Because it does not inherit from this abstract base.  It is implemented in separate compiled code, with it's own `__new__` as well as `__init__`.  Yes, it does have a lot of the same behavior, but it din't inherit any of it.

Comment: Numpy array can be 0-dim, in which case it no longer behaves like a sequence.

Comment: But also look at `np.iterable` and `abc.Iterable`.

Comment: `(1,2)*2.3` raises an error about multiplying a sequence by a float.  Those builtin sequence types implement multiply as a repeat.  Lists and strings hare similar operator definitions; `ndarray` handles most operators quite differently.  So I don't think there's much advantage to viewing a `ndarray` as `sequence`.  For what it's worth, `np.iterable` is implemented as a try/except wrapper of `iter(x)` - a good example of duck typing.

Comment: Your other question provides more context for this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76082734/how-to-check-if-an-object-can-slice

Answer (score 2):

Because it doesn't conform to any of the `collections.abc` interfaces, so specifically, `collections.abc.Sequence` should support `index` and `.count`.  `collections.abc.MutableSequence` require that as well, but also `__delitem__` and `.insert`